# Sort/short-circuit getopt flags in python

Tags: python, arguments, getopt

I have a simple [python](/questions/tagged/python) command-line application I'm currently expanding. It currently supports a couple command-line arguments:

```
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'b:h',
                               ['battle=', 'help'])
except getopt.GetoptError:
    usage()
    raise

# Parse opts/args.
for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ('-h', '--help'):
        usage()
    elif opt in ('-b', '--battle'):
        battle = True
```

I'm going to have to add LOTS of additional command-line arguments. The way I'll be implementing it, I'll have to keep track of an "is set" flag for every flag the user could set.

There are some cases where I would like to "short circuit" my parser, such as, if the user ran it with both the `-x`, `-y`, and `-z` flags, to tell the parser to skip all remaining parsing operations, and just run a specific function. However, this would would an `is x,y,z set` check for each of those options.

1. Is there a "pythonic" way to simplify parsing by allowing me to "short circuit" certain parsing operations?
2. Is it possible to guarantee I'll parse flags/opts in a specific order by sorting opt and arg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is using `getopt` a hard requirement?  Arguably the more 'pythonic' approach is to use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html#id1), a simpler, more high-level module.  In that case you can define your argparser as:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-x", ...)
parser.add_argument("-y", ...)
parser.add_argument("-z", ...)

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.x and args.y and args.z:
    short_circuit()
```

For your second question, I think that using `argparse` will remove the need to worry about parsing order, since you call each arg by name from the `args` object.

Comment: Yes, `getopt` is a hard-requirement at this time.

Comment: It's a good answer. For my current solution, messy checks. For the next project, I'll use argparse. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, with just `getopt` available, it won't be as clean as `argparse`.  You could store each seen flag in a dictionary and have a check at the end of the loop: `if all([arg in seen_args for arg in ['x', 'y', 'z']]):  short_circuit()`